# Reverse Geocoder delegate methods are not getting called?

Tags: iphone, delegates, mapkit, reverse-geocoding, mkreversegeocoder

I am working on an iPhone app which needs to find out current city/State. I am using reversegeocoding. But its delegate methods are not get called. I am not sure where I am going wrong because I looked at couple of examples. I will really appreciate if anyone help me out here.

Comment: Reverse Geocoding is under NDA as part of iOS 5. Please refrain from asking iOS 5 questions until the public release.

Comment: I did not get it .. I mean if that service is deprecated, I have Apple's Current Address example which is working perfectly fine. Can you shed some more light on this ?

Comment: **Moderator Note** We're not going to act on a question _simply_ because it might violate an NDA. If you think about it, any code snippet pasted here might _be covered under an NDA_ and unwittingly posted. We hope that programmers realize the consequences of posting code on a public forum, but we can't _possibly_ police that. The question is either on topic, or not. I realize that answers might be scarce, due to the same NDA, but that is no reason for moderator intervention. I don't work for Apple.

Comment: MKReverseGeocoder has been available in iOS since 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a map visible? I believe the service does not work without a visible map. If not, it would also violate the Google Maps API terms of service.

Comment: The service works without an visible map, but as you mentioned it violate the terms using it without a Google maps: 
"The Google terms of service require that the reverse geocoding service be used in conjunction with a Google map; take this into account when designing your application's user interface."

Comment: Actually I did not used it to show current location.I just wanted to get current city and state for search query optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the delegate property of MKReverseGeocoder and included the necessary function from MKReverseGeocoderDelegate? A method/class/service marked as deprecared means not that is does not work.